# Custom Sorting Function

Tags: arrays, function, sorting, actionscript

I am trying to sort the contents of a textbox (Which contains the names of people) alphabetically.  When the user presses the button, the contents of the textbox is supposed to sort.  This is what I have so far:

```
btn_alpha.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, alphabeticalSort);


function alphabeticalSort(Sort:Array):Array
{
for (var i:int = 0; i < Sort.length; i++)
{
    var sortArray:int = i;
    for (var ii = i+1; ii < Sort.length; ii++)
    {
        if (Sort[ii]["Name"] < Sort[sortArray]["Name"])
        {
            sortArray = ii;
        }
    }
    var temp:Object;
    temp = Sort[i];
    Sort[i] = Sort[sortArray];
    Sort[sortArray] = temp;
}

return Sort;
}
```

The program runs, but the textbox isn't sorted when the button is pressed.  The only error that comes up is when you try and press the button, it says "TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::MouseEvent@8686881 to Array."

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably get better results if you tag your question with the language you're using. It looks like it might be TypeScript?

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I'll give it a try.  I'm using ActionScript.

Comment: you cant be comparing apples to oranges Error #1034: Type Coercion hence your error: for example comparing string and numbers.... what you have in the array.. look at i? var i:int = 0;var ii = i+1; ii